# nuxtServerInit data not show in page

Tags: vuex, nuxt.js

I try to use nuxtServerInit method.
index.js

```
import productsService from "../services/productsService";
export const state = () => ({
    hotDeals: [],
    specialities: []
})

export const mutations = {
    SET_SPECIALITIES(state, payload) {
        state.specialities = payload;
    }
}

export const actions = {
    async nuxtServerInit({ dispatch}, ctx) {


      try {
        await dispatch('fetchSpecialities');
      }catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    },

    fetchSpecialities({ commit }) {
      productsService.getSpecialities()
        .then(response => {
          commit('SET_SPECIALITIES', response.data);
        });
    }
}
```

component usage

```
<template>
  <v-layout
    justify-center
    align-center
  >
      <div>

        <v-row >

          <span v-for="item in specialities">{{item.productCode}}</span>
        </v-row>
      </div>


  </v-layout>
</template>

<script>

import {  mapState } from 'vuex';


export default {

    computed: {
        ...mapState(["specialities"])
    }

}
</script>
```

But it show nonthing on page. If I try to use console.log(state.specialities) in mutation after change state I can see data in web storm console. But in component data is not showing.

Answer (score 0):

i think using watchers will solve your problem

```
  watch: {
    specialities(newValue, oldValue) {
      console.log(`Updating from ${oldValue} to ${newValue}`);
    },
  },
```